# Graph with a special condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The graph $H_n$ whose vertex set consists of $n$-lists formed by elements on the set $\{ 0,1,2 \}$. There is an edge between two vertices if and only if two $n$-lists differ in exactly one position. I am asked to find how many edges are there in this graph. I have made an attempt, but I obtained such a simple answer that I still cannot believe this can be true. Here is my approach:

To begin with, given two $n$-lists, one has to see in which position do they differ: there are $n$ positions. Now, one has to count the different pairs of numbers that differ: there are $3$ possible pairs. Once counted that, it still remains to see how many $n-1$ lists are there using the three numbers (take into account that for both lists, the remaining positions are identical): $3^{n-1}$. Using the product rule, one obtains: $3\cdot n\cdot 3^{n-1} = n\cdot 3^n$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, if you want you can check it using the handshake lemma, that says that
$$\sum _{x\in V}deg(x)=2|E|,$$
and is clear that fixed $x$ a vertex in your graph, you have that $deg(x)=2\cdot n$ because you fix the position they differ and you have two options to place a different number in the position you have chosen, because $|V|=3^n$ you get that
$$3^n\cdot 2\cdot n = 2\cdot |E|,$$
which is what you get.